# timer control in windows based application in .net?

Tags: .net, timer, desktop-application

i am creating an application, where the application will keep checking my gmailbox and if there any mail arrives, it will notify me, cuurrently i am using timer will get fired after every 10secs, it seems the application remains hang, as it checks for new mail, and the UI does not responses, is there any way where i can just check for any new mail once it arrives or something with which my application remains responsive even while timer checks for new mail, i am stuck here for last 2 weeks.

Please anyone have any idea or know some piece of code. would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you performing the check on a separate thread from the UI? If not, you'll see the hang that you describe.

EDIT: Per Ken's suggestion, adding some detail.

Here's a link to a description of threading in WinForms apps.

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml

You can keep your timer in place, but you need to spawn a thread to do the work that the timer is doing now. There may be issues with using the data from that thread within your UI. If so, you'll need to look into BeginInvoke and InvokeRequired -- or store the results of the task in a member variable (which may require the lock keyword). Hope that helps.

Comment: can you elaborate what you meant. i am simply using the timer's tick event for the check.

Comment: If the task is performed on the main UI thread, nothing else will happen until that task is done. That includes refreshing the application's widgets, or responding to user input. Your mail retrieval needs to happen on another thread, and you'll need to bring the results of that back to the main UI thread for processing in your widgets.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question; it's a comment asking for clarification. Text posted as *answers* should do just that; you may want to either edit it to provide an example of moving things to a background thread, or delete this before you start getting downvotes. :)

Comment: @Ken better? :)  [P.S. While the date of membership may indicate otherwise, I'm still quite the SO newbie. Thanks for commenting rather than downvoting.]

Comment: @groudh0g: :) Much better. And I always try to give a chance before downvoting, and always explain why I did so when I do. Thanks, and +1.